# XML request error while retrieving Sql tables in Flutter

Tags: php, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am making a project where i want to retrieve the data from Myphp admin MySql .I have created respective Json file using php and the file shows the data . But when i try requesting for the data from the file i am getting an XML request error .

Here is the output of my php file which encodes data in json format

[image]

Here is the code for the php file encoded in json format displayed in the above image

```
<?php
function get_data()
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Pitac123","localconnect");
$query = "SELECT * FROM driver";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$driver_data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $driver_data[] = array(
     'Did' => $row["Did"],
     'Dname' => $row['Dname'],
     'Age' => $row['Age'],
 );
}
echo  json_encode($driver_data);
}
get_data()
?>
```

**This driver_json.dart represents the dart file representing the json format class of mysql table**

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Welcome> welcomeFromMap(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromMap(x)));

String welcomeToMap(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Welcome {
  Welcome({
    required this.did,
    required this.dname,
    required this.age,
  });

  String did;
  String dname;
  String age;

  factory Welcome.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
    did: json["Did"],
    dname: json["Dname"],
    age: json["Age"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "Did": did,
    "Dname": dname,
    "Age": age,
  };
}
```

**This the code to retrieve the data:-**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'driver_jason.dart';

Future<List<Welcome>> fetchWelcome() async {
  var url =Uri.parse('http://localhost/localconnect/driver_select.php');
  var response = await http.post(url);
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(welcomeFromMap(response.body));
  return welcomeFromMap(response.body);
}

class DriversView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DriversView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DriversViewState createState() => _DriversViewState();
}
class _DriversViewState extends State<DriversView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
        title:const Center(child: Text("Driver")),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    ),
      body:Container(
        color: const Color(0xFF303030),
        child:FutureBuilder(
          future:fetchWelcome(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap:true,
                itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,index){
                    Welcome driver = snapshot.data[index];
                    return Text(driver.did);
                }
              );
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },

        )
      )
    ) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error that you receive?

Comment: @vipw Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 908:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22

Comment: It's probably an issue with CORS. Is your flutter app is not served from the same host:port as the webserver that serves the PHP-generated response? If not, the php server will need to handle OPTIONS requests with headers instructing the browser that it is allowed to make requests to it.

Comment: @vipw It is working for all other apis but not for php .What should I do

Comment: @vipw Now i am getting this as the output " Instance of '_Future<PostList>" after some changes im not getting the data frm php file